# How to disable scrolling in the background when the mobile menu is open?

Tags: jquery, css

I am building a mobile responsive website that has a nav menu. 
When I get to the bottom of the menu - If I continue scrolling when I reach the bottom of the menu - it scrolls the page in the background. 
How can I disable it?

This is my jQuery code so far:

```
// When the document is loaded...
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#mob-menu-btn').click(function(){
        $('.sports').slideToggle("slow");
    })

    $('#sub-menu').click(function(){
        $('.sports2').slideToggle("slow");
    })

});
```

and this is my CSS:

```
    .list{
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
        top: -10%;
        overflow: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
}


    .sports li{
        list-style-image:none;
        list-style-type: none;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #eeeeee;
        margin-bottom: 0px; 
        margin-left: 0px; 
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        width:100%;
        font-family: arial;
        text-decoration: none;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: position:fixed to body

Comment: @user3801433 but then I cant scroll the body :X

Comment: Hey Man, So when menu is on focus, you dont to scroll the body even if user reaches the botom of the menu. Please add a fiddle.

Comment: I cant publish the code :X 

Do I use the position:fixed to the whole page body? 
Or do I use it only on the div that contains the list/ul tag

Comment: When menu is open, set position fixed to the body. When you close it, remove that property. Better use add/remove class

Comment: Thank you. I succeed doing what you've said :)

Comment: Hello guys, I have an open Bounty Question here with similar situation. If there is someone willing to help, I'll appreciate it a lot. https://stackoverflow.com/q/51776867/4642215

Answer (score 35, accepted):

When a menu is open, set `position: fixed` on the body, and remove on close.

```
 .fixed-position {
    position: fixed;
 }

 if ($('#mob-menu').is(':visible')) {
    $('body').addClass("fixed-position");
 } else {
    $('body').removeClass("fixed-position");
 }
```

Comment: Is it normal that the webpage scrolls back to the beginning when setting the body fixed position?

Answer (score 29):

Instead of using `position: fixed` (which causes jumping back to the top when you open your menu) you can use `overflow: hidden`. If you are somewhere in you page and opens the menu it doesn't jump back to the top. (maybe the jumping is a problem of how i wrote my code, but it was helpful for me).

Comment: I've tried to use `overflow:hidded;` but not so sure why, in my case doesn't apply. Any thoughts please? SO Question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/51776867/4642215

Comment: Works better than `position: fixed`, because it doesn't jump back to the top. Thank you!

Comment: Beware `overflow:hidden` doesn't fix the problem on iOS.

Comment: It doesn't seem to fix anything in modern browser. I can still scroll.

Comment: @JamesSmith Which version? It works well in my tests on iOS.

Comment: @LarsVandeDonk dont foget to set body height:100%

Answer (score 19):

To offer an alternative solution to the "scrolling mobile menu" problem, instead of controlling the `overflow` property, you may wish to try setting the following on your menu:

```
touch-action: none;
```

Assuming the menu fully overlays the main content, whether the user has the address bar open or close, scrolling with touch is prevented.

You will find it is fairly well supported: https://caniuse.com/?search=touch-action. Depending on your use case, this may be neater.

Comment: Clever solution to an age old problem!

Comment: this is clutch. Works great everywhere I've tested so far

Answer (score 18):

There is also slightly different approach to this problem. You can add an `onclick` event to your button. Then add/remove class to your body (similar as previous answer, but taking the one before it into consideration).

Add this to your *head* section:

```
<script>
      function lockScroll() {
            document.body.classList.toggle('lock-scroll');
      }
</script>
```

Then define the class in CSS:

```
.lock-scroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}

<button type="button" id="mob-menu-btn" onclick="lockScroll();">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Fix the body height:

```
body.js-mobile-menu-open {
    overflow: hidden;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

None of these solutions worked for me - but I found one that does.

My issue when trying some of these answers was that I had `overflow-y: scroll` set on the `html` element - which prevented this code from working.

`height: 100%` also didn't do the trick on my end - but `100vh` did.

The following works for me:

```
html {
  overflow: auto;
}

body.js-mobile-menu-open {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Another solution would be to remove `overflow-y: scroll` from the `html` and applying these `body` styles.

Answer (score 2):

I would just make a minor change to the @roko's answer because I could never get the else statement to fire.

```
$("body").toggleClass("fixedPosition");
```

Then styling:

```
.fixedPosition
 {
    position: fixed;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

i tried the lockScroll() and it worked, but i found that if the menu closes by accident not using the hamburger menu, the body still have the lockscroll class and you cant scroll anymore, worse if you click again the burger menu button, it removes the class and then you can scroll with menu open and cant with menu closed

Answer (score 0):

In React/Nextjs you can target the body by traditional javascript methods - just add

```
const body = document.getElementById("body")
body.classList.toggle("fixed_body")
```

to handleClick function like this:

```
const handleClick = () => {
    const body = document.getElementById("body")
    setShowAside(!showAside)

    body.classList.toggle("fixed_body")
  }
```

And the class looks like this:

```
.fixed_body{
   overflow: hidden;
   block-size: 100%;
 }
```

and ofcourse add id to the body

```
<body id="body">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a simple answer that worked for me using a little bit of jQuery and CSS.

As you want to make the body fixed while the menu opens you need to create a CSS class to make the body fixed which we will add later with jQuery.

```
`.fixed {
 position: fixed !important;
```

}`

Now create a function that adds this fixed class to the body while the menu opens.

```
jQuery( ".menu-toggle" ).click( function() {
        jQuery("body").toggleClass('fixed');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

##### OK, If you encounter this problem in 2023

I will list the solution for

Vanilla JS

Astro

NextJS/React

### VanillaJS

You need to add a class name to your Global CSS File with the following:

```
  nav_open {  
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    }
```

Then in the navbar (Mobile menu) file add the following

> // target the body and the toggle  (input)  element

```
const toggle = document.getElementById("toggle");
const body = document.querySelector("body");
```

> // Add Event listener to the changes on the input element and pass a
> function

```
toggle.addEventListener("change", overflowDisable);
```

> // Create the function which will conditionally add/remove the class
> from the body

```
function overflowDisable() {
  if (toggle.checked) {
    body.classList.add("nav_open");
  } else {
    body.classList.remove("nav_open");
  }
}
```

Done

---

### Astro

In Astro, it's really very simple

> You need to add a class name to your Global CSS File with the
> following:

```
 nav_open {  
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    }
```

> In the navbar.astro file (Or whatever filer where is your navbar code)
> open a script tag  and follow the same as above in Vanilla JS

```
<script>

  const toggle = document.getElementById("toggle") as HTMLInputElement | null;
  const body = document.querySelector("body");

  toggle.addEventListener("change", overflowDisable);

  function overflowDisable() {
    if (toggle.checked) {
      body.classList.add("nav-open");
    } else {
      body.classList.remove("nav-open");
    }
  }

</script>
```

> Note: In Astro, you will need to add  `"as HTMLInputElement | null;"`
> to the document or you will get an error

---

### NextJS React

Here the approach will be different we will use [useState & use Effect] hooks

You need to add a class name to your Global CSS File with the following:

```
  nav_open {  
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    }
```

Next, in you navbar.jsx / navbar.js file

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
```

> Note: if you are in NextJs Version 13+ App-Router, you will have to add this to the top of the navbar.jsx file in the first line

```
"use client";
```

//First, initiate the state hook

```
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)
```

//It will be false by default of course until the user active the mobile menu

pass the event value to the state  setter function

```
const overFlowDisable = (e) =>{   //note event is deprecated use (e)

setChecked(e.target.checked)

}
```

// Second, Initiate the useEffect hook

```
useEffect (() => {  
  
  // I will use the Conditional (ternary) operator, You can use the normal if/else statement but I found this more concise
  
    checked ? document.body.classList.add("nav_open") :
    
        document.body.classList.remove("nav_open")
      
      },[checked])
```

> Note: don't forget to pass the handler function and the checked state variable to the input element, it should look like this

```
 <input className={styles.toggle_check_box}
                onChange={overFlowDisable} checked={checked}
                type="checkbox" id="toggle"></input>
```

> Final thoughts: There is the `"touch-action: none;"` method I tried
> before but it didn't work and even if it works it stops the full touch
> functionality (which means you can't touch or press anything on the
> screen)

Answer (score 0):

I tried most of these, and it just sets the page back to the top again and that's not what I wanted. The simplest solution I found was setting the HTML overflow to hidden using JavaScript.

```js
document.querySelector('html').style.overflow = 'hidden';
```

Worked like a charm and didn't affect where the user was on the page

Answer (score 0):

So while being in this pickle myself at end of 2023 I came up with such a whacky solution using my beloved, alive and kicking jQuery with vanilla JS.

This event is connected to the hamburger menu button and assumes body does not start with class touch-none:

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  let lockedScroll = 0
  $('YOUR_ICON_CLASS_OR_ID').click(function() {
    lockedScroll = window.scrollY
    $('body').toggleClass('touch-none')
  })
  $(window).on('scroll', function (e){
    if($('body').hasClass('touch-none')){
      e.preventDefault()
      document.body.scrollTop = lockedScroll
      window.scrollTo(0, lockedScroll)
    }
  })
})
```

**Vanilla:**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  let lockedScroll = 0   
  document.
    querySelector('YOUR_ICON_CLASS_OR_ID').
    addEventListener('click', function () {
      lockedScroll = window.scrollY
      document.body.classList.toggle('touch-none')
    })
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
    if (document.body.classList.contains('touch-none')) {
      e.preventDefault()
      document.body.scrollTop = lockedScroll
      window.scrollTo(0, lockedScroll)
    }
  })
})
```

This forces body to stay on the same scroll position, returns it to saved position in case it scrolled someplace and does not reset webpage back to top.