# How to prevent body from scrolling with push-side menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to properly implement a push-side menu plugin ([Responsive Menu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-menu/)) into a wordpress theme. Based on [SO @Congrim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49763914/4642215) answer, I've managed to achieve a way to lock the `body` at scroll when push-menu is open (with all the elements including the `header` fixed) except the interactive links `class=edge-ils edge-ils-with-scroll edge-ils-light` which will still go Up at push-menu open.

I've saved this sequence into `congrim.js` file, I've enqueued the script into the theme in `functions.php` file:

```
function lockScroll() {
    if ($('body').hasClass('lock-scroll')) {
        $('body').removeClass('lock-scroll');
    }
    else {
        $('body').addClass('lock-scroll');
    }
}


/* I've implemented `onclick="lockScroll();"` in button element, 
 * using this sequence in the same congrim.js file:
 */    

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#responsive-menu-pro-button').click(function() {
       lockScroll();
    }); 
});
```

Removing the jQuery wrap will not give any error in browser console (tested in Chrome) may be still a bad approach to wrapp the code like this in wordpress (?)
In these conditions, unfortunately, `overflow: hidden;` doesn't apply, at push-side menu open, I can't use this class in CSS file/section:

```
.lock-scroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The code will allow me to use only

```
.lock-scroll {
    position: fixed;
}
```

**The question:**
Is there any possibility to force the code to implement <s>`overflow: hidden;`* OR any other</s> a workaround in order to have the interactive links `class=edge-ils edge-ils-with-scroll edge-ils-light` not going up at push-side menu open, to remain fixed at the position the viewer is clicked before opening the menu?

Please focus on the interactive links issue only, the rest of the scene is fine (`header` and the `logo` are in place like it should be, the background pictures are acting like it should as well).

LE: *`overflow: hidden;` it looks like will produce an unwanted `body` shifting effect at menu open/close, during the show/hide scrollbar, which is not happening in this stage.

LE2: `congrim.js` file has been replaced with [`body-lock.min.js`](http://www.neuegrid.com/wp-content/themes/anders/assets/js/modules/plugins/body-lock.min.js) by Outsource WordPress, please see the solution below.

Website testpage [here](http://www.neuegrid.com/ilinks-push).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check the solution given below.

**Step 1:** Add this CSS `.scroll-lock{position:fixed !important;}`.

**Step 2:** Add this JS.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var windowTop = 0;
    var menuOpen = 0;
    var offsetContainerList = 0;

    $('#responsive-menu-pro-button').click(function() {
        var offsetScrollList = $('.edge-ils-item-link:first').offset().top; 

        if ($('html').hasClass('scroll-lock')) {
            $('#responsive-menu-pro-container').one("webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend",
              function(event) {
                  if (menuOpen==0) {
                      menuOpen = 1;
                      $('html').removeClass('scroll-lock');  
                      $('.edge-ils-content-table').css('top', eval(offsetContainerList)-40+'px'); //change image container top position
                      $('html').scrollTop(windowTop); //scroll to original position
                  }
                  else {   
                      menuOpen = 0;             
                  }
            });
        }
        else {                
            windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            offsetContainerList = $('.edge-ils-content-table').offset().top;  
            $('html').addClass('scroll-lock');      
            $('.edge-ils-content-table').css('top', -offsetScrollList + 'px'); //change image container top position
        }      
    }); 
});
```

That's it!

Comment: Thank you SOOO much for this wonderful solution Sir, you're a Champ! It works like a charm, so smooth and nice. I really appreciate it, as much as others will appreciate this workaround for sure! All the best,

Answer (score 0):

Your scroll isn't a natural navigator-based scroll, you have a JS somewhere swapping classes to emulate a scroll (`edge-appeared`,`edge-up`,`edge-down`).

On the push-side menu opening, these classes are reset, `overflow-hidden` won't change that.

You need to find which JavaScript is swapping those classes and prevent it from doing so, I'd be glad to be of further help but you have so many JS files that it would take quite some time to go through all of these. If you succeed in making a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please post it here.

Comment: Thanks but for the same reason I am unable to do that (because there are a lot of files involved into that scene); more than that, as I already said, I'm not a coder, I have no knowledge to do that, compiling and taking the essence from all that files ... Thanks for passing by and for your time, anyway. I appreciate it,

Comment: Maybe you can try asking the Responsive Menu support, it seems they already had this kind of issue [here](https://responsive.menu/forums/topic/slide-goes-within-behind-page-scroll-push-comes-over-top/). Good luck !

Comment: I already had a discussion with @[Peter Featherstone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1836618/peter-featherstone), but it looks like there are not much to do and I thought that there are people that had this issue and develop an solution; Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below code in your custom js file .

```
 jQuery('#responsive-menu-pro-button').click(function(){
    var menu_active = jQuery(this).hasClass('is-active');
    if(menu_active){
        jQuery('body').css('position','fixed');
    }else{
       jQuery('body').css('position','static');
    }
});
```

I hope it helps you.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you, I've updated the `congrim.js` file, adding your sequence below the existing code. It looks like this will lock the `body` not on menu-open but on menu close. Please have a [look](http://www.neuegrid.com/ilinks-push). Did I've made something wrong? [here](http://www.neuegrid.com/wp-content/themes/anders/assets/js/modules/plugins/congrim.js?ver=4.9.8) is the file.

Comment: Hello @typo_ please add only one code for lockScroll, remove all the reaming code in your file http://www.neuegrid.com/wp-content/themes/anders/assets/js/modules/plugins/congrim.js?ver=4.9.8

Comment: remove all the code add test by using my code only, otherwise it will create problem.

Comment: see this link i have check with console https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R5EV1saMYjbTWpVjxhBlqiX3avt78Q40/view

Comment: Done! Should I add the line below the code as well jQuery.fn.init (...) ? or  should I remove the `.lock-scroll {
    position: fixed;
}` ?  still not [working](http://www.neuegrid.com/ilinks-push) Should I replace `jQuery` with `$` ? (I know that's unusual for wordpress but I've managed to make other code work using `$` instead of `jQuery`.

Comment: Anyway, I suppose that there is a misunderstanding. In your video the links are fixed but not in the scroll-to-top position or any other position, only at the initial position. I thought that I've said "not going up" - into the initial stage. I appreciate it,