# How to prevent body from scrolling with Responsive menu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

I am trying to properly implement the [Responsive Menu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-menu/) plugin into a wordpress theme. The issue appears when the push-side menu is open, which cause `body` to move at vertical scroll.

At this moment, there is a solution for [this template page](https://www.neuegrid.com/ilinks-push/) that is working amazing and I'm happy with the result.

**The question:**
Taking in consideration [Outsource WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51908621/4642215)'s answer, which fix the above specified page, is there any possibility to tweak the below code in order to be usable in more general way in other template pages as well for example [here](https://www.neuegrid.com/scroll-lock/) like already is running [here](https://www.neuegrid.com/ilinks-push/)?

I suppose that `.edge-ils-item-link` and `.edge-ils-content-table` are variables but I have no idea how to approach and adapt this, I've made some tests replacing these elements but with no positive results, maybe it's not that simple, it's more than that. I also know that `edge-wrapper`, `edge-wrapper-inner`, `wpb_wrapper` are found in every pages, these could be the common elements that could change the solution making it available for every page.

Also it will be great to be jQuery ready according to the latest version (at this point I am using jQuery migrate 1.4.1 and an old version of Wordpress in order to be functional at least on the page designed for).

`.scroll-lock{position:fixed !important;}`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var windowTop = 0;
    var menuOpen = 0;
    var offsetContainerList = 0;

    $('#responsive-menu-pro-button').click(function() {
        var offsetScrollList = $('.edge-ils-item-link:first').offset().top; 

        if ($('html').hasClass('scroll-lock')) {
            $('#responsive-menu-pro-container').one("webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend",
              function(event) {
                  if (menuOpen==0) {
                      menuOpen = 1;
                      $('html').removeClass('scroll-lock');  
                      $('.edge-ils-content-table').css('top', eval(offsetContainerList)-40+'px'); //change image container top position
                      $('html').scrollTop(windowTop); //scroll to original position
                  }
                  else {   
                      menuOpen = 0;             
                  }
            });
        }
        else {                
            windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            offsetContainerList = $('.edge-ils-content-table').offset().top;  
            $('html').addClass('scroll-lock');      
            $('.edge-ils-content-table').css('top', -offsetScrollList + 'px'); //change image container top position
        }      
    }); 
});
```

Video with the issue, if this helps [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nvpWusqiF9vRcZiX6Dvz3uA2xt4UYp5F/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Have you tried to use the insert header and footer plugin to add the code on every page?

Comment: As long as this jQuery sequence contain elements from a specified page `.edge-ils-item-link` and `.edge-ils-content-table` (but not from every page) it doesn't matter how we implement the code. It's about finding other general elements that are present in every pages for example `edge-wrapper`,`edge-wrapper-inner`, `wpb_wrapper`. I've tried to replace the elements with the last mentioned testing [this page](https://www.neuegrid.com/scroll-lock/) but I guess that is more than that, it's not behaving well.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle with this issue? I would be happy to look into the problem as long as it's isolated from your site, as that would guarantee that the problem is well-defined. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately the theme is too complex to summarize and reproduce it into a jsfiddle. Thanks anyway.

Comment: is this still not fixed??

Comment: @Moayad.AlMoghrabi Unfortunately nope. Any idea about how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Hey, I could definitely help you with this, could you provide a link to your site?

Comment: thanks, sure, I have issues with  [this page](https://www.neuegrid.com/scroll-lock/).

Comment: It looks to be a simple issue, but you just didn't give us the tools to help you, please provide a clean example (without any added code) of the page you want it to work on, and explain what is the expected result, from what I understood, when the menu opens, you want the right to be un-scroll-able, and the text to stay as is?

Comment: @Art3mix I agree but the theme is too complex to let me isolate the code,sorry.Please watch the [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nvpWusqiF9vRcZiX6Dvz3uA2xt4UYp5F/view?usp=sharing) to see what is the expected result. The page that is working fine is [this one](https://www.neuegrid.com/ilinks-push/), and the issue appear on [this page](https://www.neuegrid.com/scroll-lock/). The page content should remain in the last position when the menu is opening/closing without getting back o top, moving around, whatever.If you watch these 2 pages and the video you'll see the differences. Thank you!

Comment: At menu open, the right vertical scroll should be locked and also the page content in the last position (no matter in what position is scrolled). The info field is always locked in that position. At menu close, everything should get back to normal.

Comment: Again, the page you want it to work on have the wrong code included, we can't test things on page that is not working, create a new example page, remove the JS code you tried to have a fresh start.

Comment: I can do that, no problem if this helps.

Comment: @Art3mix Done! removed the js/css code. Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first lets talk about the issue:

The plugin is setting `transform: translateX(800px);` on your main div, but, transform remove the `position: fixed` from all of its children, so all your inner divs that have position fixed, are basically moved to be position relative so they are basically moved to the top.

***The Too Complex Solution:***

You can of course play with scrolling the user to the top, saving what position he was, and do a real complex solution to workaround this issue, BUT, all of this for a left menu? it seems to be so much work for a simple fixed div that push other fixed div to the right.

***The Easy Solution:***
Why wouldn't we just omit the transform, and use margin-left?

```
<style>

html.responsive-menu-pro-open {
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
  padding-right: 9px;
} 

#responsive-menu-pro-container {
  position: fixed !important;
}

#responsive-menu-pro-container {
  position: fixed !important;
  transform: none !important;
  margin-left: -800px;

  transition: 2.6s ease; 
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.96, 0, 0.13, 1); 
  transition-property: margin-left; 
}

#responsive-menu-pro-button {
  transform: none !important;
  transition: 2.6s ease !important; 
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.96, 0, 0.13, 1) !important; 
  transition-property: margin-left !important;
}

.responsive-menu-pro-open #responsive-menu-pro-button {
   margin-left: 800px;
}

#responsive-menu-pro-header {
  transform: none !important;
  transition: 2.6s ease; 
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.96, 0, 0.13, 1); 
  transition-property: margin-left; 
}

.responsive-menu-pro-open #responsive-menu-pro-header {
  margin-left: 800px;
}

.responsive-menu-pro-open .edge-wrapper {
  transform: none !important;
}

.responsive-menu-pro-open .edge-wrapper .edge-wrapper-inner {
  margin-left: 800px;
}

.edge-wrapper .edge-wrapper-inner {
  transition: 2.6s ease; 
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.96, 0, 0.13, 1); 
  transition-property: margin-left; 
}

.responsive-menu-pro-open .edge-content .edge-ps-navigation {
  margin-left: 800px;
}

.edge-content .edge-ps-navigation {
  transition: 2.6s ease; 
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.96, 0, 0.13, 1); 
  transition-property: margin-left; 
}

.responsive-menu-pro-open #responsive-menu-pro-container {
  margin-left: 0;
  transition: 2.6s ease; 
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.96, 0, 0.13, 1); 
  transition-property: margin-left; 
}

.responsive-menu-pro-open .edge-back-to-top-text {
  display: none;
}

</style>
```

By adding the snippet above, you mimic the functionality you want without transform using margin-left.

*Notes* - because of your page layout (its a bit of a mess, a lot of position fixed elements, inside other position fixed elements), you need to set margin-left to different elements, changing the page layout would make it much easier to apply this, or even use the native transform functionality of the plugin.

This solution might only work on the example page you gave us, you will need to set marign-left on the correct elements on your other pages, but again, if you layout all of your pages into a single wrapper div, that will hold the functionality, and remove other fixed elements, you will be able to create a single code snippet that will work on pages.

***Bottom line*** - the plugin have issues because of your page layout, contacting the plugin developers might give you a better answer, and they might look into your specific theme and bring a much better solution.
Without seeing your code this is the best work-around I could find without trying to play with scrolls.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the class of `scroll-lock` is not getting added to the html element in your page called "scroll-lock", but it is added on the "ilinks-push" page. So the if checking if the html has this class will never become true on your sub pages. I rewrote the code so it will look for the inteded class called `responsive-menu-pro-open`.

But moreover to make it work for your subpages, you need to understand the logic in the provided code. I did some changes and added comments to make it more clear:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var windowTop = 0;

    $('#responsive-menu-pro-button').click(function() {

        /* check if there is a ils item link */
        if ( $('.edge-ils-item-link')[0] ) {
            /* save space above the element to variable */
            var offsetScrollList = $('.edge-ils-item-link:first').offset().top;
        }

        /****** Menu gets opened ******/

        if ($('html').hasClass('responsive-menu-pro-open')) {

            /* scroll to top of page */
            windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); 
            /* add the scroll-lock class */
            $('html').addClass('scroll-lock');
            
            /* check if there is a ils item link */
            if ( $('.edge-ils-item-link')[0] ) {
                /* add the saved space again to look like the same scroll position we started with */      
                $('.edge-ils-content-table').css('top', -offsetScrollList + 'px'); 
            }
            
        }

        /****** Menu gets closed ******/

        else { 
            $('html').removeClass('scroll-lock');

            /* check if there is a ils item link */
            if ( $('.edge-ils-item-link')[0] ) {
                /* again use the saved space to make it look like the start position */
                $('.edge-ils-content-table').css('top', -offsetScrollList +'px');
            }

            $('html').scrollTop(windowTop);
        }

    }); 
});
```

You see the parts where there is `check if there is a ils item link` written?

This will be the parts that are different on your subpages.

With using `.offset().top` we are getting the space above the elements. This will only work, if there are actually elements with the class of `.edge-ils-item-link` which is why I put the code inside of the if clauses.

In the code you are using the spaces above to position the elements in the right place, so it will look like the scroll is blocked.

To target the right elements, we need the class of it.

So you have to make sure, that every page uses the same class around the content area. This way you are able to target them on every page without additional if clauses in the javascript.

Alternatively you could right a bounch of if clauses and check the elements in your pages. In your page called "scroll-lock" it might be the element of `info-field` you can use to set the spaces. But in this page you have the content placed with fixed position (don't know why, are you using some fancy block builder or something? markup looks aweful), so this causes problems, when adding your class of `scroll-lock` with the `position: fixed;`.

I think you need to adjust the content of your other pages, so this problem can be solved for you. It will not be a good practice to adjust the javascript for every of your subpage with different content elements. Try to make every subpage in two columns (using flexbox). Maybe the left one will always be fixed and the right one is static and therefore scrollable. We don't know this with the information given in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 1-I am trying to minify it and I receive [this error](https://imgur.com/mWsOI2X.jpg). 2- This code will replace the above exposed code as far as I understand; Should I remove also `.scroll-lock{position:fixed !important;}`?

Comment: I also have to mention that I'm not a coder, (zero knowledge in js/jquery) I'm just trying to solve this issue, finding a way to make Responsive menu to work properly with this current wp theme.

Comment: Thank you, I've replaced the code inside [body-lock.min.js](https://www.neuegrid.com/wp-content/themes/anders/assets/js/modules/plugins/body-lock.min.js?ver=4.9.16) but unfortunately, no positive effect on [this page](https://www.neuegrid.com/scroll-lock/). I believe that this could mean something but not so sure why it doesn't work ..yet. I see an error in the console (by the way, browser clear, incognito mode).

Comment: Here: [error](https://imgur.com/inuTx4x.jpg) and [(details)](https://imgur.com/jkrVckL.jpg). I guess that is related to back to top function(?) I'll let the code updated if this helps, until your first reply.

Comment: I edited my answer. Don't know if it helps, if you can't read javascript in general. Moreover the markup generated by your editor is horrable... You need to make sure to have some consistency in your subpage html markup, otherwise you cannot target the elements.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it doesn't work, it's acting weird. The point is that the original body-lock.min.js code is working fine for the [target page](https://www.neuegrid.com/ilinks-push/) and imho, I suppose that the key is to find a way to replace the existing defined elements (eg. `.edge-ils-item-link` and `.edge-ils-content-table`) with general elements that are present in every pages for example `edge-wrapper` ,`edge-wrapper-inner`, `wpb_wrapper`.

Comment: In this way will be covered both situations. I have no idea how but that's the strategy. On the other hand if there is not a way to define multiple variables, I don't mind if there will be 2 different codes one for each page as long as I suppose that there could be a way to activate the plugin for a specific page(s).

Comment: `.edge-ils-item-link` and `.edge-ils-content-table` are used into a Visual Compser blocks, that's why these are not general elements find in every pages. It doesn't help if we rewrite the code using the same elements, will not affect [this page template](https://www.neuegrid.com/scroll-lock/).

Comment: To conclude, in order to be more clear, I am happy with the existing code implemented for [target page](https://www.neuegrid.com/ilinks-push/). I am trying to tweak the code in order to have the same effect on [this template page](https://www.neuegrid.com/scroll-lock/) too changing somehow the variables.

Comment: I got your point and your question. But the reason I can't help you is the structure of your other template page (not the working one). All I can target is the info-field, which may not be present on your other pages... or is this the only possible other page structure of your pages? You need something that is being scrolled down (!) to check the space above the element. but as your info-field is fixed from the beginning, we need the images. but they have a strange markup, not getting what this visual composer is doing... what are you using btw?

Comment: This is pretty rough I know. info-field is the only element that should remain fixed (not scrolled). anyway, I am using [Anders theme](https://themeforest.net/item/anders-a-clean-multiconcept-portfolio-theme/20054026?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIuPntxIHV7gIVWdTtCh3vwAeFEAAYASAAEgJiF_D_BwE)  and this include Visual Composer aka WPBakery Page Builder with predefined blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Add `min-height: 100vh;` to the body tag. It will show verticle scroll only if the content exceeds the viewport height.

Currently, the document height in your pages is locked to the total height of relatively positioned children. Refer below screenshots.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I suppose that will goes like [this](https://imgur.com/2T9Z2td.jpg)? nope it doesn't work. Anyway, as I've said, the above code made by @OutsourceWordPress is made only for a particular [page](https://www.neuegrid.com/ilinks-push/), not for every page that's why it's not functional in a general way. Thank you anyway for your time.

Answer (score 0):

So regrading to what I understood according to the required behavior, I think the solution is simple, and no need to complicate it:

I was looking at the pages and the script behavior and found out that the class **scroll-lock** is not being added to the DOM, but you can I think simply just count on the class name: **responsive-menu-pro-open** that is being added to the HTML element after opening the menu, So just try to set some CSS properties to this class and I think you are set to go. Please confirm.

```
.responsive-menu-pro-open{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps as I've tried it at my own end and it worked perfectly :)

Comment: Thank you, It could be a place to start and an approach but here is the [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15sI6Sfx2QFa12JVn-jP3nexpgLawSB7J/view?usp=sharing). The sliding panel could be partial scrolled when the menu is closing (should remain fixed) also the links/images are misbehaving, getting back to top at open/close menu sequence. Another issue, the info-field is moving as well. Something is not right ...

Comment: @typo_ OK I see, let me check on what to do

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this problem is in fact with the Wordpress plugin you are using, called [Responsive Menu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-menu/), which allows you to edit those options. I use it on my site, [Couv's Corner](https://couvscorner.com).
Here are some trouble-shooting solutions:

- Make Sure the plugin is up to date, it has updated recently and is much better.
- Sub-Menus (Menu Items nested under parent categories) are the best. Use them anywhere necessary. Customize this in the "Menus" Page of your admin dashboard.
- Check your theme. [Kadence WP](https://wordpress.org/themes/kadence/) is a good one. Play around some, b/c your theme may have a conflict.
- Try running a site database/file optimization and clearing your cache/cdn if you use them. That may help you fix the issue.
  Hope this helps. Be sure to check out the plugin, as well as how I have it set on [my site](https://couvscorner.com), to see what you think.