# How to prevent page scroll to the top while menu opened

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is a menu button on the page. When a user taps the button full-page menu opens. There is a problem - the main content page automatically scrolls to the top. Could you advise me on how to prevent it? I've already checked a similar question here [How to disable scrolling in the background when the mobile menu is open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230955/how-to-disable-scrolling-in-the-background-when-the-mobile-menu-is-open), but nor position:fixed or oveflow:hidden helped

```js
const menuOpen = document.querySelector('.menu-open');
const menuClose = document.querySelector('.menu-close');
const body = document.querySelector('.root');

function lockScroll() {
    body.classList.add('lock');
}

function unLockScroll() {
    body.classList.remove('lock');
}

menuOpen.addEventListener('click', lockScroll);
menuClose.addEventListener('click', unLockScroll);
```

```css
.lock {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.menu-open {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all ease 0.6s;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  padding: 1rem 1rem 2rem 2rem;
}

.nav-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #f5f5f1;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
            <button type="button" class="menu-open"><img src="./images/menu.svg" alt=""></button>
            <div class="nav-container">
                <button type="button" class="menu-close"><img src="./images/close.svg" alt=""></button>
                <div class="menu__wrapper">
                    <div class="socials">
                        <img src="./images/logo.png" alt="" class="logo" title="">
                    </div>
                    <nav class="menu">
                        <div class="menu__item">
                            <a class="menu__item-link">menu</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="menu__item">
                            <a class="menu__item-link">menu</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="menu__item">
                            <a href="#males" class="menu__item-link">menu</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="menu__item">
                            <a class="menu__item-link">menu</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="menu__item">
                            <a class="menu__item-link">menu</a>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
```

doesn't help.

Comment: cancel the click action

Comment: seems it doesn't work, now the menu is opened at the top. So if I've opened the menu at the middle of the page I should go to the top to watch it

Answer (score 2):

I think your main body elements are positioned static (or relative if defined?), untill you change it by overriding with position fixed.

A better behaviour would be to leave your nav container be positioned absolute on "menuOpen" and leave the remainder of elements in their already defined flow so your full screen simply overlay's the rest of the elements.

Comment: thanks, but in such a way here is another problem - user can scroll the page while the menu is opened

Comment: I see what you meant and did some searching: this is by far the cleanest solution i found (bookmarking this myself as well)

https://malin.codes/how-to-make-a-scrollable-menu-without-scrolling-the-body/

Essentially it uses the same approach as position fixed on the body element, but does it on a wrapper around the nav-container. This prevents stacking flow of all elements that are outside of the wrapper. As scroll behaviour is only being triggered on the nav-container within the wrapper. 

It seems this one does the trick very cleanly

Comment: thanks a lot, your comment helped. I added classes html.noscroll {overflow: hidden;}body.noscroll {overflow: visible;height: 100%;} to menu container when it is open and everything works ok

Comment: Good to hear ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience (mostly WordPress), `event.preventDefault();` does the trick. You basically override the default behavior when clicking a link - which opens a page on the top.

Used in this way:

```
const menuOpenable = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-item-has-children");

menuOpenable.forEach((menuItem) =>
  menuItem.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const subMenu = event.target.parentElement.querySelector(".sub-menu");
    subMenu.classList.toggle("sub-menu--open");

    event.preventDefault(); // <-- Here
  })
);
```